# Can't install tflite-model-maker in jupyter notebook

Tags: android, jupyter-notebook, tflite

I’m writing an application for Android in which I need text classification, I tried creating models through conversion to tflite, but there were errors in Android Studio that the model is not tflite, and tflite-model-maker in google colab is endlessly installed

I was advised to `%pip install tflite-model-maker` in jupyter-notebookm but I have difficulties

When installing the module I get an error

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [68 lines of output]

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
  
          This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
          calls to avoid build errors in the future.
  
          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.

  !!
    parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
  running egg_info
  writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last) 
...

...
[end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

And this error occurs if you download modules from the requirements file

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-support>=0.4.2 (from versions: 0.1.0a0.dev3, 0.1.0a0.dev4, 0.1.0a0.dev5, 0.1.0a0, 0.1.0a1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite-support>=0.4.2
```

Link to requirements file and information [here](https://pypi.org/project/tflite-model-maker/)

Help, I’m new to jupyter notebook, and I just want to make a text classification model for an android application

Comment: My suggestion of `%pip install tflite-model-maker` was based on that generally being a good way forward in modern Jupyter. There seems to be a super complex installation triggered by that though **in this particular case**; it's something about this module. I see a completely different failure then you though. I see a conflict caused by `numba` and `tflite-support` and "these package versions have conflicting dependencies.". You can go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/millefy-binder), click on 'launch Millefy in JupyterLab', & then run `%pip install tflite-model-maker` to see what I see.

Comment: <continued> [Here in this issue thread entitled 'Can't install tflite-model-maker from pip or github' started in March](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59855) someone reported success with Python 3.9. Where I was trying to install has Python 3.10. [Someone in that same thread reports getting it working on Google Colab](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59855#issuecomment-1639071082), which you mention in your first paragraph.